# Nginx: serving static files from multiple locations (probably very easy to solve)

Tags: nginx

I have a very simple case of serving static files via nginx yet I can't figure it out.

I want all URLs beginning with /static/ to serve static files from directory /foo/bar/dir1 and if the file isn't there, serve from /foo/bar/dir2, if not there, return 404.

So for example when handling URL /static/some/file.png I want nginx to first try

```
/foo/bar/dir1/some/file.png
```

and then

```
/foo/bar/dir2/some/file.png
```

I know I should probably use something like this

```
location /static/ {
  try_files .... something .....
}
```

but the documentation on try_files is very unclear to me. I tried a lot of combinations but nothing seems to work. Multiple alias directives would do the job but it won't work. I think the solution must be very simple but I cant get it right. It's kind of hard to debug how nginx resolves all these locations and files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the root (make sure to update the try_files after). And also make sure there is no root directive in `location /`

```
location ~* ^/static/(.+)$ {
        root /;
        try_files /foo/bar/dir1/some/$1 /foo/bar/dir2/some/$1 =404;
}
```

Edit: Removed the need of the static folder.